# Group by month, day, hour + gaps and islands problem

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, query-optimization, gaps-and-islands

I need to calculate (in percentage) how long was status true during day, hours or month (working_time).

I simplify my table to this one:

```
| date                      | status    |
|-------------------------- |--------   |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:21.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:22.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:23.125Z  | true      |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:24.125Z  | false     |
| 2018-11-05T19:04:25.125Z  | true      |
....
```

I need to get in result (depend on parameter) this one:

for hours:

```
| date                      | working_time |
|-------------------------- |--------------|
| 2018-11-05T00:00:00.000Z  | 14           |
| 2018-11-05T01:00:00.000Z  | 15           |
| 2018-11-05T02:00:00.000Z  | 32           |
|...                        | ...          |
| 2018-11-05T23:00:00.000Z  | 13           |
```

for months:

```
| date                      | working_time |
|-------------------------- |--------------|
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z  | 14           |
| 2018-02-01T00:00:00.000Z  | 15           |
| 2018-03-01T00:00:00.000Z  | 32           |
|...                        | ...          |
| 2018-12-01T00:00:00.000Z  | 13           |
```

My SQL query looks like this:

```
 SELECT date_trunc('month', date)                                         as date,
       round((EXTRACT(epoch from sum(time_diff)) / 25920) :: numeric, 2) as working_time
FROM (SELECT date,
             status as current_status,
             (lag(status, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date)) AS previous_status,
             (date -(lag(date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY date))) AS time_diff
      FROM table
     ) as raw_data
WHERE current_status = TRUE AND previous_status = TRUE
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date)
ORDER BY date;
```

and it works ok but really slow. Any idea about optimisation? Maybse using Row_Number() function?

Comment: Do you need to count consecutive `TRUE` or any rows in designed period as `TRUE`?

Comment: I need to count consecutive TRUE. Let me write little example:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   SELECT t.month_reference as date,
            round(  sum(if(t_aux.status,1,0))  / 25920) :: numeric, 2) as working_time
```

#I asume you use this number because is the uptime of the system 60*18*24,

#I would use this if I wanted the total seconds in the month 60*60*24*day(Last_day(t.month_reference))

```
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month', t.date) as month_reference
          FROM table
         ) as t
    left join table t_aux
    on t.month_reference=date_trunc('month', t_aux.date)
```

so when we group by month, the sum() will only find the rows that are true and have the referenced month

```
   and t_aux.date < 
    (select t1.date 
    from table t1 
    where t.month_reference=date_trunc('month', t1.date) 
    and t1.status=false 
    order by t1.date asc limit 1 )
```

I add this so it only selects the rows that are true until it finds a row with status false in the same month reference

```
    GROUP BY t.month_reference
    ORDER BY t.month_reference;
```